# Regex_replace Postgres - Check if <= 2 characters length

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need 3 characters minimum for users accounts. I reuse existing names like

"`tata-fzef` - `vcefv`" or "`kk`" from the `IMP_FR` field to make this accounts.

In the second exemple, "`kk`" should become "`k_k`" because less than 3 characters.

How to do it with Postgresql?

```
regexp_replace( IMP_FR , regexp, first_character + '_' + last character, 'g')
```

Comment: You do not really have to use  a regex for this. With regex, it will look like `regexp_replace('kk', '^(.)(.)$', '\1_\2')`, but what if the input is just 1 char?

Comment: Good question, i was not in this cas. But if 'k' it should become '_ k _' . _ before and after the only caracter

Comment: Then you still need an `if` condition, and you can forget about regex as PostgreSQL regexp does not support conditional replacement patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it solves my problem .

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions won't help much here since `REGEXP_REPLACE` does not support conditional replacement patterns. You need different replacement pattern here for cases when the input only contains one, two or three or more chars.

So, it is better to rely on `CASE ... WHEN ... ELSE` here and the regular string manipulation functions:

```
CREATE TABLE tabl1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO tabl1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('tata-fzef - vcefv'),
    ('kkk'),
    ('kk'),
    ('k')
;

SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN LENGTH(s) = 1 THEN '_' || s || '_'
       WHEN LENGTH(s) = 2 THEN LEFT(s,1) || '_' || RIGHT(s,1)
       ELSE s
    END AS Result
FROM  tabl1;
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/XPC39024). Result:

[image]